# Javascript: How to handle syntaxError in response string parsing

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, syntax-error

In my HTML file, I have a single line (below) that gets a response from a device over WiFi & makes data available to my JavaScript, it works well except when there is an error in the response text & it halts.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.4.1/"></script>`

The response is a text string representing JavaScript variables, it sometimes gets corrupted throwing an error.

**Examples:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand side  192.168.4.1:14:3  
      SyntaxError: unterminated string literal  192.168.4.1:3:8
```

I need a solution to capture the error of parsing the received string so I can run the above statement again to get a new string.

Thanks

below is a picture of the response string (JS variables.)

[image]

The issue is that once the script is loaded, its content might be misformed and I would like to  avoid having errors due to that.

Update #1.  get the data with XMLHttpRequest

```
<script>
   const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   const url='http://192.168.4.1/';
    Http.open("GET", url);
  //  Http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    Http.send();
  ReturnVar = Http.responseText
  Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => { console.log(Http.responseText) }
</script>
```

Below is the detail in browser Console, Headers after script above run.

```
   GET
    scheme  http
    host        192.168.4.1
    filename    /
    Address 192.168.4.1:80
    Transferred 1.82 KB (1.82 KB size
```

```
Request headers (278B)  
GET / 
Host: 192.168.4.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Comment: `The response is a text string` could you shown an example of the response

Comment: What do you get as a response to the request to that IP address?

Comment: I get a multi-line string representing JS variables, (below).
When I enter address in browser I get the text, When I refresh page I get new data.
I can see corrupt strings sometimes by another device connecting at same time.

var s1=['Ah','A','TTFDR'];
var s2=[0,1,5,0,7,2,2,0,3,5,1,1];
var s3=['ON','3.56','25.8','1936'];
var DT="18/10/2020-17:50";

Comment: (there are 4 lines in above response starting with var (this page is not rendering the newline)

Comment: The example you have given does not reproduce the problem. Can you provide an example for a Javascript that you receive and is not parsing?

Comment: I can't give an example of a response that gives error now, but looking at the corrupt string it has missing characters that would clearly generate a syntax error as if It were in my source code html file: such as missing quote, missing brace, missing comma etc...).

Answer (score 1):

You have a script tag, which is loading the script and evaluating its content. You need to programmatically modify this, so you need to

## Get the file as a text

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/

You just need to programmatically download the content the file, not as the `src` of a `script`.

## Evaluate it

Before you proceed, read this: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Now, that you know that `eval` is not exactly popular - and rightly so - and if you are still sure you need to run a script as it is, study [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and make it work equivalently as it was

## Encapsulate it into try-catch

Example for error:

```
eval("'");
```

Example for error in try-catch:

```
try {eval("'")} catch (ex) {}
```

Comment: The code in Update #1 works to get the data, I can see reply string under 'Reponse payload', but it is blocked from JS, ReturnVar = ""

error at script end...  
```Cross-Origin Request Blocked:CORS header‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)```    
         
 
I am stuck how to enable JS to access the response, I don't know how to set the Reference for 'header' in code example (update #1)

Comment: I put the following line after Http.open... line:
```Http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');```
I can see "Access-Control-Allow-Origin *" now in browser console, Request headers, but still get ```Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.4.1/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)```

Answer (score -1):

you can call the address using ajax, and then if the response is in json you can easily use it, but if its some sort of script or something else, wrap it in a script tag an append it to the body.
assume the `result` is what you got from ajax request and you have jQuery in your project:

```
$('body').append('<script>'+result+'</script>')
```

in this case you can wrap your code in try catch and handle the errors